# ArgumentNullException in an array that I can't figure out

Tags: c#

I have been up half the night and still trying to get this null exception figured out. I have read a few of texts about this issue but none has helped me in any way, to me what the problem is as it should work :/  It just crashes at this piece of code:

```
Private void UpdateGUI()
{
    string selectedItem  = cmbDisplayOptions.Items[cmbDisplayOptions.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    rdbtReserv.Checked = true;            
    lstReservations.Items.Clear();           
    lstReservations.Items.AddRange(m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(selectedItem));
}
```

`lstReservations.Items.AddRange(m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(selectedItem));` Gives me the ArgumentNullExeption, but to me it should not do that.

the addrange sends string selectedItem to another class:

```
    public string[] GetSeatInfoStrings(string selectedItem)
    {
        int count = GetNumOfSeats(selectedItem);

        if (count <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string[] strSeatInfoStrings = new string[count];

        for (int index = 0; index <= m_totNumOfSeats - 1; index++)
        {
            strSeatInfoStrings[index] = GetSeatInfoAt(index); 
        }

        return strSeatInfoStrings;

    }
```

This `int count = GetNumOfSeats(selectedItem);` goes to here and returns with an int:

```
    private int GetNumOfSeats(string selectedItem)
    {
        if (selectedItem == "ReservedSeats")
        {
            return GetNumReserved();
        }
        if (selectedItem == "VacantSeats")
        {
            return GetNumVacant();
        }
        else
        {
            return m_totNumOfSeats;
        }
    }
```

I have checked the arrayed have the correct number of spaces(60) and that `selectedItem` has a string(Allseats to start with so it should return `m_totnumOfSeats` which is an int of 60) But then in the `private int GetNumOfSeats` something goes wrong and it returns null and...well why?

I can't see the problem.. maybe gone blind by trying to find the issue. Always got outstanding help here and I have learned tons!! So maybe someone can point out all the issues there is in my code.

Thanks a million in advance for any and all advice!

//Regards

Comment: Is `m_seatMngr` null at the time of the exception?

Comment: check the stacktrace and if possible post to help finding the exact line of code giving the error.

Comment: @user1501127 you have some logical errors in your program!Try to debug your program by setting  break points and checking the values in your variables

Comment: Is there any reason why you create the string array with size `count`, but then fill it with `m_totNumOfSeats` values?

Comment: You will find the answer here, but you should also learn how to debug a program (asap). You can resolve such an issue yourself in a minute or two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your variables are actually initialized and returns correct values.

There are logical errors in the GetSeatInfoStrings methods and the GetNumofSeats method.

Lucky for you the GetNumOfSeats method will always return 60 for you because of the wrong way you compare strings. It's not the right way, so use the Equals method for comparison like

```
 if (selectedItem.Equals("ReservedSeats"))
```

With that you will get a proper output form GetNumOfSeats(string) method.

The next thing is to fix your looping in the GetSeatInfoStrings method so as to not get an array index out of bounds exception like this.

```
    string[] strSeatInfoStrings = new string[count];

    for (int index = 0; index <= count; index++)
    {
        strSeatInfoStrings[index] = GetSeatInfoAt(index); 
    }

    return strSeatInfoStrings;
```

Also fix the part where your logic returns a null in the GetSeatInfoStrings method. it should return an empty string array according to your logic  as

```
    return new string[0];
```

That should probably get your methods working. You need to be very careful of what you code before you debug it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code of ObjectCollection, when you call AddRange and pass a null value, you get back the ArgumentNullException.

You could prevent this changing this code

```
if (count <= 0) 
{ 
    return new string[0]; 
}
```